# Spring Profiles org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-profiles

My sample project is Maven based structure, all my application proeprties files under `src/main/resources` folder. Below is the complete sample code. I am not understanding why my code not able to find profiles properly unless I use `@PropertySource` annotation.

**My actual doubt is:**  I've configured spring properties pretty well in application.properties file, but yet why it cannot find profile and their respective property files? Unless I am using `@PropertySource` annotation, iam not getting value for env.getProperty("mysql.url"). I mean `Environment` class not able to pick up values from profiles property files. **WHY?**

**Iam getting error as below:**

```
Jul 08, 2017 7:54:26 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@300ffa5d: startup date [Sat Jul 08 19:54:26 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
helloBean
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'datasource' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084)
    at com.oreilly.datasource.Main2.main(Main2.java:15)
```

**DatasourceConfig.java**

```
package com.oreilly.datasource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
/*@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:/dev/application-dev.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:/prod/application-prod.properties")*/
public class DatasourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name="helloBean")
    public String helloWorld() {
        System.out.println("helloBean");
        return "helloWorld....";
    }

    @Bean(name="datasource")
    @Profile("dev")
    public DataSource datasourceForDev(){
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("mysql.url"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name="datasource")
    @Profile("prod")
    public DataSource datasourceForProd(){
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("mysql.url"));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**Main2.java**

```
package com.oreilly.datasource;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DatasourceConfig.class);

        DataSource dataSource = context.getBean("datasource", DataSource.class);
        String helloBean = context.getBean("helloBean", String.class);


    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
spring.config.name=application
spring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties,classpath:/dev/application-dev.properties,classpath:/prod/application-dev.properties
```

**Below is the project folder structure:**

[image]

**Please tell me what went wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue just by modifying as below:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/${spring.profiles.active}/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties")
```

Now I am able to pickup application-dev.properties (or) application-prod.properties dynamically.

**Note**: `Environment` class requires @PropertySource annotation, otherwise we get null for env.get('someproperty').

Answer (score 1):

Spring is smart, it chooses the application-x.properties (where x is the environment) depending of the value assigned to spring.profiles.active in the application.properties, so you don't have to worry about register all the files in different @PropertySource annotations.

You can get more info here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

I suggest you remove all the @Profile annotations and let just one datasource that will be variable (depending on the seleced environment from application.properties). You may understand this with the example that i put at the end of this post.

If you want to define a mysql.url for a particular profile (lets say dev), you need to add the "mysql.url" in the application-dev.properties file, and then set the spring.profiles.active value to dev in application.properties.

Then, in your DatasourceConfig.java, you can perform something like this:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

//Takes the mysqlUrl from application-x.properties (where x is the value of spring.profiles.active that comes from application.properties)
@Value("${mysql.url}")
private String mysqlUrl;

@Bean(name="helloBean")...

@Bean(name="datasource")
public DataSource datasource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    System.out.println(mySqlUrl); //This value is variable depending of the profile that you're pointing on.
    return dataSource;
}
```

Please let me know it this is useful for you.

Comment: An additional comment: You need to define your application.properties and application-x.properties files in the resources root in order to Spring detects them automatically.

Comment: I think you should understand my query properly.. we should use Environment class instead of declaring each property variable like "mysql.url"... I have kepted @Profile annotation to declare 2 profiles (dev and prod) using 2 methods..

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DatasourceConfig {
....
}
```

put property file in same location as application.property and follow the naming convention application-{profile}.properties like application-dev.properties, application-prod.properties.

---

*'I want properties file to be picked up automatically based upon profile I declared in application.properties.'*
:

Run you application with -Dspring.profiles.active=dev/prod . Spring load 1)application.property , 2)pplication-dev/prod.properties file with overides value from application.property

Comment: I want properties file to be picked up automatically based upon profile I declared in application.properties.. Any Idea?

Comment: Without using @PropertySource should work, how? I mean it should pickup my application-dev.properties automatically, how?